# Application Error "SQLSTATE[42000]"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I build restful API and its work, but when I try to pass a parameter to the link an error displayed below, although when I print the parameter the result is correct!

Details

> Type: PDOException
>
> Code: 42000
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
>   `Journal_name` like 'Abhinav%' AND is_reported=1' at line 1
>
> File: ...path/index.php
>
> Line: 15
>
> and line 15 is "$stmt = $db->query($sql);"

**index.php**

```
<?php

// index.php 

require 'confing.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/rout', function() use ($app) {
    $db =getDB();
        $title = $app->request()->params('title');
        // echo 'title ='. $tilte print the correct title name get it by link
    $sql = "SELECT J_name FROM J where where `J_name` like '".$title."%' AND is_reported=1;";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
    $pre = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $sql2 = "SELECT P_Name FROM P where `P_Name` like '".$title."%' AND is_reported=1;";
    $stmt2 = $db->query($sql2); 
    $pre2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo json_encode($pre);
    echo json_encode($pre2);
});
$app->run();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two times `where condition` in your query that's wrong.

```
$sql = "SELECT J_name FROM J where where `J_name` like '".$title."%' AND is_reported=1";

                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Remove one `where`

It would be

```
$sql = "SELECT J_name FROM J where `J_name` like '".$title."%' AND is_reported=1";
```

Comment: It's happen something !! anyway enjoy

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question directly, but it's worth pointing out because it's an extremely serious security issue.  The way you are constructing your queries opens you up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations).

The reason is that you are directly interpolating user-provided input (in this case, `title`) directly into a database query.  Someone could use that to interpolate and execute their own, malicious SQL within your query.

One of the advantages of PDO is that it allows parameter binding, which protects you from SQL injection.  So instead of:

```
$db =getDB();
$title = $app->request()->params('title');
$sql = "SELECT J_name FROM J where `J_name` like '".$title."%' AND is_reported=1;";
$stmt = $db->query($sql); 
$pre = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

You can do:

```
$db =getDB();
$title = $app->request()->params('title');
$sql = "SELECT J_name FROM J where `J_name` like :title AND is_reported=1;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute([
    ':title' => "$title%"
]);
$pre = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Notice how I have removed the variable `$title` from the query itself, and I am instead binding it to a placeholder `:title` inside a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Now, PHP will construct the actual "code" portion of the query separately, an introduce the variable `:title` later.  Even if the variable `$title` contains malicious SQL code, it won't be treated as SQL code - it will be treated as simple text, just like anything else.